# Bash script to check git commits of last 2 days

Tags: bash, git, shell

I am trying to write a bash script which checks if there are any commits of a repository and returns a message. Here is the script so far.

```bash
MY_PATH="C:/test"
cd "$MY_PATH"
git clone https://github.com/test-repo/docker-react.git
cd "docker-react"
git checkout master
if [[ -n "`git log --pretty=format: --name-only --since="200 days ago" | sort | uniq`" ]]
 then
 echo -e No Commits last 2 days
 else
 echo -e Commits available
fi
```

When I execute this code it always show commits available even when I change the days.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `--since="200 days ago"` really?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bash script, which would be interpreted by the Git for Windows bash shell.

It means it should be checked with ShellCheck, which would then recommend:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
MY_PATH="C:/test"
cd "$MY_PATH" || exit
git clone https://github.com/test-repo/docker-react.git
cd "docker-react" || exit
git checkout master
if [[ -n "$(git log --pretty=format: --name-only --since="200 days ago" | sort | uniq)" ]]
 then
 echo -e No Commits last 2 days
 else
 echo -e Commits available
fi
```

Not yet ideal: ideally, it would check if the repository is not *already* cloned. But it should work better.